# Display Grid Cards cut when I resize the window in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, layout, css-grid, grid-layout

I have created cards with html and scss using a two colum grid to divide the entire screen in two, because I want to display the cards in the left half of the screen, and then I use again grid to display the cards in rows of two columns. The problem is that when I resize the window the cards are not updated and the content (image, shadow, etc) are cut. This issue only happens in Chrome. I identify that is when I added the animation to menuitem class. And only on development mode (localhost). When the app is deployed it doesn't have any issues.

here is the html:

```
  <div class="appContainer">
    <div>
        <h3> Pizza </h3>
        <div class="menu__list">
            <div class="menuitem" style="background-image: url(https://hips.hearstapps.com/hmg-prod.s3.amazonaws.com/images/delish-keto-pizza-073-1544039876.jpg?crop=0.668xw:1.00xh;0.233xw,0.00255xh&resize=480:*);">
                <span class="menuitem_title"> Cheese Pizza </span>
            </div>
            <div class="menuitem" style="background-image: url(https://hips.hearstapps.com/hmg-prod.s3.amazonaws.com/images/delish-keto-pizza-073-1544039876.jpg?crop=0.668xw:1.00xh;0.233xw,0.00255xh&resize=480:*);">
                <span class="menuitem_title"> Pepperoni Pizza </span>
            </div>
            <div class="menuitem" style="background-image: url(https://hips.hearstapps.com/hmg-prod.s3.amazonaws.com/images/delish-keto-pizza-073-1544039876.jpg?crop=0.668xw:1.00xh;0.233xw,0.00255xh&resize=480:*);">
                <span class="menuitem_title"> Chicken Pizza </span>
            </div>
            <div class="menuitem" style="background-image: url(https://hips.hearstapps.com/hmg-prod.s3.amazonaws.com/images/delish-keto-pizza-073-1544039876.jpg?crop=0.668xw:1.00xh;0.233xw,0.00255xh&resize=480:*);">
                <span class="menuitem_title"> Veggie Pizza </span>
            </div>
       </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Here is the css:

```
.appContainer {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
}

.menu__list {
    max-width: 100%;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    grid-gap: 30px 50px;
}

.menuitem {
  height: 200px;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  border-radius: 26px;
  box-shadow: 3px 4px 9px 0px #32322e;
  padding: 20px 0 0 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin-top: 5px;
  filter: contrast(80%);
  transition-property: margin-top filter;
  transition-delay: 0.1s;
  transition-duration: 0.2s;

  &:hover {
    margin-top: 0px;
    // margin bottom to push the bottom item, and not make it move!
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
    filter: contrast(100%);
    width: 100%;
    }
  }
```

The app without resize:

[image]

The app when I drag the window and make it bigger, or drag the window to another monitor with different resolution, if I reload the cards are displayed correctly:

[image]

Here is what the inspector shows:

[image]

here is the plunkr, you can reproduce the issue here dragging the line that separates the code from the preview as the image shows:

[image]

https://plnkr.co/edit/FDl8WiVxj1mcq65UTXra?p=preview

I don't know what else to try, I have to fix this because if I load the window when the browser is not maximized and then I maximize the browser the images are cut.

Comment: Consider loading the image with an `<img>` tag instead of through the CSS.

Answer (score 0):

You could try getting rid of the padding on menuitem and put it on the title instead.

```css
.menuitem {
    height: 200px;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    border-radius: 26px;
    box-shadow: 3px 4px 9px 0px #32322e;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin-top: 5px;
}

.menuitem_title {
    display: block;
    padding: 20px; 
}
```